# Devices renamed with udev not working, original device node still there

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udev, v4l2

I'm trying to rename certain video devices using udev. Here's a rule (broken down for readability):

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{busnum}=="1",
ATTR{devpath}=="2", ATTR{idVendor}=="05e1", NAME="video97"
```

It works. /dev/video97 is created
But the original /dev/video1 node is STILL there.

The even worse, when I try to view the /dev/video97 node in guvcview it doesn't work, while the original node DOES work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is actually allowed to rename kernel device names; in fact, recent udev shows a warning about such rules.

Try using `SYMLINK+="video97"` instead.

Comment: That's correct. Also: I wasn't actually naming the video device, but the usb key itself. The usb device had some "virtual" devices